# Error is SQL Server: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here? What I am trying to do is, I want to get information of the people who are followed by the people who follow a person that, suppose I, follow. Here, 1003 is the userid of the person who I am already following and 1001 is my userid

```
SELECT USERID,
       USERNAME,
       PHOTO,
       COUNT(FOLLOWER)
FROM   USERS
       LEFT JOIN FOLLOW
              ON USERS.userid = Follow.following
WHERE  USERID IN (SELECT FOLLOWING
                  FROM   FOLLOW
                  WHERE  FOLLOWER IN (SELECT FOLLOWER
                                      FROM   FOLLOW
                                      WHERE  FOLLOWING = 1003)
                  GROUP  BY USERID,
                            USERNAME,
                            PHOTO
                  EXCEPT
                  (SELECT FOLLOWING
                   FROM   FOLLOW
                   WHERE  FOLLOWING = 1003
                           OR FOLLOWER = 1001))
```

Comment: If you remove the EXCEPT part, does it work? (Divide and conquer... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm)

Comment: @jarlh I'm afraid it does not work even if I remove it

Comment: `GROUP BY ... COUNT(FOLLOWER)` is certainly incorrect. aggregate functions like `COUNT` run on the groups created by the `GROUP BY` so can't be referenced in it itself. But also seems like the rest of the columns you are attempting to group by aren't even from that table. Unclear what you are trying to do with that. Why do you even need that `GROUP BY` before the `EXCEPT`?

Comment: @MartinSmith yes sorry, I didn't notice that I had added COUNT(FOLLOWER) in the group by. But even if I remove it, it shows the same error

Comment: Just remove the whole `GROUP BY`. You aren't doing any aggregation so don't need it

Answer (score 0):

you just need to join `FOLLOW` table again as another set of your followers `1001` and your friend `1003`.

```
SELECT USERID, USERNAME, PHOTO, COUNT(f1.FOLLOWER) 
FROM USERS 
LEFT JOIN FOLLOW ON USERS.userid = Follow.following 
LEFT JOIN FOLLOW as f1 ON f1.following = Follow.following and f1.FOLLOWING IN (1001, 1003)
```